# Having trouble applying an external font to CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family, text-styling

I downloaded a free font and have the .ttf file in a folder on my local server. However, I can't seem to be able to get the font to actually work. This is the code that I found online for applying an external font:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: simplifica;
    src: url(fonts/simplifica.ttf) format('truetype');
}

    .header {
  font-family: simplifica;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

To clarify, I did change the file name because I read somewhere that capital letters can cause unexpected problems for browsers like IE. The original file name was "SIMPLIFICA Typeface.tff".

Also, I am using Brackets text editor and it's "live preview" function.

Comment: I just read that the 'truetype' format is for Safari/Android/iOS from this source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/.

However, the font is still not displayed when I access my site from a mobile device.

Comment: Putting quotes around each simplifica does not seem to work either.

Comment: Moving the font file into the same folder as the stylesheet and changing the src to "src:url('simplifica.ttf')" seems to have done the trick. Is there something I'm inputting incorrectly in order to keep this font file in a separate folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't other formats, try convert this font with https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 1):

Try to Import other font formats like woff and eot and try this code

```
@font-face {
font-family: simplifica;
src: url(fonts/simplifica.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
   url(fonts/simplifica.woff) format('woff'),
   url(fonts/simplifica.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

if the font folder is the same place as the css folder who contain the css file replace "fonts/" with "../fonts/"

Comment: Unfortunately, the only file that was provided was the .ttf file.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: Thank you for the font converter link as well, I didn't know these existed lol